# Multiple messages in message queue

Tags: c, multithreading, process, message-queue

This is probably a really dumb question, but googling isn't working out so here goes. I am writing a program using message queues to send a range of values to different processes. I have done research that indicates that I use msgsnd() to store a message on the queue and msgrcv() to receive messages. I need to store a start number and an end number in the queue. So my question is can I store multiple messages in this queue and if so, how to I go about storing them and retrieving them? TIA for all your help.

Comment: Err..call `msgsend` and `msgrecv` once for each message. Is that too obvious an answer or are you asking something else more subtle?

Comment: Isn't it in the name? It's a message **queue** - so you can send several messages, and you'll receive them in the same order you sent them in.

Comment: Yeah I knew people were going to be insulting. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of a [queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)) means you can put things in (`msgsnd`) which creates one message in the queue. To receive one message, you have to call `msgrcv`. Each receive will normally only return one message, so if you send `n` messages, you have to receive `n` messages.

Queues are generally seen as FIFO (first in, first out), so the message creates by the first `msgsnd` will be the first message returned by `msgrcv`. 
This is a little weakend if you message queues that operate over the network (and/or in a cluster). Due to network latency/failover/retries etc messages can get out of order, so it's generally advised to build the messages with all necessary information in them to process correctly for those cases.